# .htaccess file doesn't work for home page

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Following .htaccess doesn't work for root level page.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^demo\-blog/(.*)$ demo\-blog/index.php/$1 [L]
```

If I access http://example.com/demo-blog/blog/publish.html then it works by executing file on http://example.com/demo-blog/index.php/blog/publish.html but when I access http://example.com/demo-blog/ it doesn't load the page from http://example.com/demo-blog/index.php. The .htaccess file is on the domain root. http://example.com/

Please let me know why it doesn't rewrite the url for the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^demo-blog(/.*|)$ demo-blog/index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I only commented out matching the directory like following. #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  My matching works without any change.

Comment: Yes it will work with your regex also but if you enter URL like this `http://example.com/demo-blog` (no trailing slash) then it won't.